# Program will not continue to next function, Python 3

Tags: python

I have to create a modularized code for a simple program but i cannot get past entering the grades.

The program asks for 5 grades and then it calculates average of the grades and tells user the number and grade.

I tried making a main module but after getting errors i took it out and still getting errors:

```
grade1 = int(input('Please enter a grade: '));
grade2 = int(input('Please enter a grade: '));
grade3 = int(input('Please enter a grade: '));
grade4 = int(input('Please enter a grade: '));
grade5 = int(input('Please enter a grade: '));

total = float(grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5)

def calcAverage(total):
   average = float(total/5)
   print('The average grade is ' + average)
   return average

def determineGrade(average):
    if average >= 90:
        print('That is an A.')
    elif average >= 80:
        print('That is a B.')
    elif average >= 70:
        print('That is a C.')
    elif average >= 60:
        print('That is a D.')
    else:
        print('That is a F.')
```

I do not really know exactly what I did wrong, but when I try to change it up there is an error that a variable is not defined and i delete it. I have tried to call the other functions and return variables with no difference.
I am using python 3 language.

Comment: This code runs without error, but it doesn't do much of anything. (You define two functions but never call them.) If you want help understanding an error you're getting, you're going to need to show us the actual error you're getting and the code that caused it.

Comment: This line `print('The average grade is ' + average)` will raise an exception since you're trying to add an int to a string. Replace it with: `print('The average grade is {}'.format(average))`

Comment: I believe I simply need to call the functions but I do not know what to type into python, I deleted the error parts so hold on while I try to figure out what put.

Comment: Functions are pieces of code you're supposed to call elsewhere in your program, and at this point, you've only defined them as stated earlier. If you don't call them in some way they won't do anything. I think you need a Python tutorial.

Comment: the error was   NameError: name 'average' is not defined   when i would try to call the functions at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only error I encountered when calling your functions was that `average` in the line containing `print('The average grade is ' + average)` in the `calcAverage` function needed to be cast as a `str`. Try the following:

```
grade1 = int(input('Please enter a grade: '));
grade2 = int(input('Please enter a grade: '));
grade3 = int(input('Please enter a grade: '));
grade4 = int(input('Please enter a grade: '));
grade5 = int(input('Please enter a grade: '));

total = float(grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5)

def calcAverage(total):
   average = float(total/5)
   print('The average grade is ' + str(average))
   return average

def determineGrade(average):
    if average >= 90:
        print('That is an A.')
    elif average >= 80:
        print('That is a B.')
    elif average >= 70:
        print('That is a C.')
    elif average >= 60:
        print('That is a D.')
    else:
        print('That is a F.')

average = calcAverage(total)
determineGrade(average)
```

Output from a sample run:

```
Please enter a grade: 89
Please enter a grade: 90
Please enter a grade: 44
Please enter a grade: 56
Please enter a grade: 88
The average grade is 73.4
That is a C.
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked, i was not sure how to change that specific variable